# How to load a table which sum the values (from database) when clicking the check box. in an onchange function in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a fees billing form. when selecting a student name from a drop-down I want to load a table which contains there pending fees(from the database).
I know that simple but.in the table i want to display fees when clicking the checkbox I want to sum up the fees amount.

iam succeed in loading table and summing up the value. but when I merging the code. the summing is doesn't work

> index.php

```
<select id="housename" onchange="show_fee_table(this.value);">                                       
<option value="" >Select</option>  
<option value="1" >name1</option> 
<option value="2" >name2</option> 
<option value="3" >name3</option> 
<option value="4" >name4</option>                                                                                
</select>

<div id=txtHint></div>


<script>
function show_fee_table(str) {
var xhttp;  
if (str == "") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;
}
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "get-fee-details.php?q="+str, true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

> get-fee-details.php

```
//actully this datas suppose to load from datatbase.


<form name=form1 >
<table class='table table-striped' >
<tr ><th >FEES name</th><th >status</th></tr>
<tr ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=100 onclick='chkcontrol(0)';> fee = 100 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
<tr><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=200 onclick='chkcontrol(1)';> fee = 200 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
<tr  ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=300 onclick='chkcontrol(2)';> fee = 300 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
<tr ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=400 onclick='chkcontrol(3)';> fee = 400 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>

</table></form>

<br>

<div id=msg></div>


<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">        
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function chkcontrol(j) {
var sum=0;
for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){

if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
sum = sum + parseInt(document.form1.ckb[i].value);
}
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Sum :"+ sum;
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Sum :"+ sum;
}}
</script>
```

i also need to get id of the checkbox when processing the payment so that i can change status not paid to paid

any other methodes are also welcomed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">        
</script>
<form name=form1 >
<table class='table table-striped' >
<tr ><th >FEES name</th><th >status</th></tr>
<tr ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=100;> fee = 100 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
<tr><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=200 ;> fee = 200 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
<tr  ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=300;> fee = 300 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
<tr ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=400 ;> fee = 400 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>

</table></form>

<br>

<div id=msg></div>

<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">   

</script>
```

and on your js.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var sum = 0;
$('body').on('click', '.due-fee', function() {
   var status = '';
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      sum += parseInt($(this).val());
      status = 'Paid';
   } else {
      sum -= parseInt($(this).val());
      status = 'Not paid';
   }
   $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).find('td:eq(1)').text(status);
   $('#msg').text(sum);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now :) .can u do one more favour? i also need to get which checkbox checked so the when submitting i can change NOT PAID status to Paid?

Comment: Please check once again.

Comment: yey, it working and i need this way. but I mean when I click submit. i need to update this paid status in my database. so somehow i need pass id of it(in a database there is an id to each fee) so any suggestions so that i can achieve it. ANyway very thankew for code It Helped :)